# Find textarea inside a table row and replace it's value with Jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

html

```
 <tr id="rowID"><td class="from"><textarea class="inputTextarea">text</textarea></td></tr>
```

provided I know the rowId, how do I replace the text inside textarea?

Answer (score 1):

got it

```
 $("#" + rowId + " textarea.inputTextarea").val(newValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the text area in a single CSS based selector, which will return the textarea for the row with rowID. Then we change its text value using the `val` jQuery function:

```
$('#rowID td textarea.inputTextarea').val('value goes here');
```

Answer (score 1):

you do not need any classes if you have only one td or one textarea. (at least not for jquery)

```
$('#rowID td textarea').val('VALUE')
```

if you have multiple textareas, this will replace the value in all of them. if you dont want that make sure to include the specific textarea or td class:

```
$('#rowID td.from textarea.textArea').val('VALUE');
```

Edit: for multiple textareas you can alternatively also use other selectors like:

```
$('#rowID td:eq(2) textarea').val('VALUE')
```

will change the value in all textareas in the third column of the given row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function changeText(rowID, data)
    {
        $("#" + rowID + " textarea").val(data);
    }

    changeText("rowID", data);
```